# Updating dictionary values using zip() in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, zip, nested-lists

I have 4 lists of floats which I have extracted from a JSON file. I have to modify the values in these 4 lists simultaneously, depending on the first list. I am using zip() to iterate over all the 4 lists, but I am unable to *update the values in the original dictionary representing the JSON*.

I need to check the sign of an element in first list, if it is negative, all the values in the 4 lists which have the same index as that element have to be zeroed out. The following code snippet contains some sample data:

```
{
   "channels": [
      {
         "name": "TTZAR1e", 
         "samples": [
            {
               "data": [0.0996781, 0.0177724, -0.00566106],
               "modifiers": [
                  {"data": [0.084338, 0.0103356, 0.010294], "type": "staterror"}, 
                  {"data": {"hi_data": [0.0996781, 0.0177724, -0.00566106], "lo_data": [0.0996781, 0.0177724, -0.00566106]}, "type": "histosys"} 
                ], 
               "name": "conv"
            }
         ]
      }            
  ]
}
```

And here's what I've tried so far:

```
import json 
file = open("test1.json", 'r')
json_data = json.load(file)

for key, value in json_data.items():
    for i in value:
        for samp in i.get('samples'):
            for mod in samp.get('modifiers'):
                hi_list=[]
                lo_list=[]
                if(mod.get('type') == 'staterror'):
                    stat_list = mod.get('data')
                if(mod.get('type') == 'histosys'):
                    hi_list = mod.get('data').get('hi_data')
                    lo_list = mod.get('data').get('lo_data')
                for val, val2, val3, val4 in zip(samp.get('data'), hi_list, lo_list, stat_list):
                    if (val<0):
                        val,val2,val3,val4  = 0,0,0,0
```

When I print the JSON, I still get the original negative values. The final output I am working towards is something like the following:

```
{
   "channels": [
      {
         "name": "TTZAR1e", 
         "samples": [
            {
               "data": [0.0996781, 0.0177724, 0],
               "modifiers": [
                  {"data": [0.084338, 0.0103356, 0],"type": "staterror"}, 
                  {"data": {"hi_data": [0.0996781, 0.0177724, 0], "lo_data": [0.0996781, 0.0177724, 0]}, "type": "histosys"} 
                ], 
               "name": "conv"
            }
         ]
      }            
  ]
}
```

I would like to know how to update the values in the dictionary itself. Is there a way to implement this here?

Comment: I think your loop is the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks @U12-Forward :) I am not able to propagate the changes to the dict values though...I am sure I am missing some important step here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zip()` creates a list of tuples. These tuples do not share any memory with the original lists, meaning that you have no way of mutating the inputs to `zip()` using what it returns.

You should store references to the lists that you want to modify, and then modify them in-place. (I will note that you should seriously consider simplifying this code, as the high nesting depth makes this code hard to read and debug.) Here's a code snippet that does that:

```py
for key, value in json_data.items():
    for i in value:
        for samp in i.get('samples'):
            lists_to_modify = [samp.get('data')]
            for mod in samp.get('modifiers'):
                if(mod.get('type') == 'staterror'):
                    lists_to_modify.append(mod.get('data'))
                if(mod.get('type') == 'histosys'):
                    lists_to_modify.append(mod.get('data').get('hi_data'))
                    lists_to_modify.append(mod.get('data').get('lo_data'))
            for data_index in range(len(samp.get('data'))):
                if samp.get('data')[data_index] < 0:
                    for list_to_modify in lists_to_modify:
                        list_to_modify[data_index] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much @BrokenBenchmark for the explanation, it works :)) By simplifying, are you referring to the multiple "for" loops ?

Comment: Yes. The JSON data itself contains a lot of nesting, so I can see why these loops might seem necessary, but you're going to need to keep track of a lot of different variables at once. For example, I had to use `data_index` rather than `i` in the bottom `for` loop, since `i` was used in an outer loop. Using descriptive names as well as reducing nesting helps readability and makes it easier for you and others to identify any issues that might come up with your code.

Comment: Yes, indeed the json itself has a lot of nesting, which cannot be changed, and lead to these for loops. I will make sure to add the descriptions to the nested loops to make it more readable, thanks again for the solution and the tips !

Comment: @Manlai and @BrokenBenchmark
I have a quick follow-up question for updating the json file. I am trying the following to produce a new json file with the changes as above -  
`with open("test1.json", 'r') as file:
 json_data = json.load(file)
       (the above modifications)

with open("new.json",'w') as file1:
 file1.write(json.dumps(json_data,indent=3))`
But in my new json file, the values are printed vertically in a new line, instead of the format in the original json. Is there a way in which this issue can be solved ? Thanks !